# JavaNNS can't find dll

Tags: java

I have problem with installing javanns. I get java.lang.Exception:

> The system couldn't find the library SNNS_jkr JavaNNS couldn't start

I tried to do everything, what I have found in Google. Maybe somebody faced with same problem, and can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem downgrading java version to 1.3 on my PC.

Comment: so what was the issue with higher versions of java.

Comment: @anant666 i don't know, but there was file "SNNS_jkr.dll" in the folder with JavaNNS installer. And installer of javanns was telling me, that it's couldn't find this library(SNNS_jkr). I think, in the newer version of java some necessary libraries was deleted.